# Disable snaps booting at startup

Tags: boot, snap, systemd

I have Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy and I am just a noob user, so I do not have deep technical understanding, so please say everything simply.

I ran `systemd-analyze blame` and I see, that there are lot of snap apps mounting and I want to disable them, so I ran `sudo systemctl disable snapd.service`, `sudo systemctl disable --now snapd.seeded` and `sudo systemctl disable --now snapd.socket`, but after reboot I still see these apps mounting in the `sytemd-analyze blame`. What should I do to disable them?

Thank you very much for every idea.

Comment: There are a number of snaps that run by default with Ubuntu. Would you like to completely remove `snapd` from your system?

Comment: Review the impact of snaps across more than one reboot to get a more realistic understanding of their impact, which is generally much smaller than some folks think. Disabling or removing snapd is not a solution that is supported by the Ubuntu Developers. You can do it (it's your system), but if you encounter unexpected behavior they will reject bug reports.

Comment: Do you find Ubuntu is slow booting?  If so it is usually the first few items in blame that slows booting down the most.  Most snaps, not all, can be replaced with .deb version of program.

Comment: Well, I do not want to remove it, I just want to make them mount when they are runned. It is for me slow compared to Lx Mint, which I had some time ago. Thanks.